# How to play a different sound file from res>raw

Tags: android, kotlin, android-music-player

Under class I have

```
private lateinit var mp: MediaPlayer
```

Under override I have

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a1)
```

Function `buttonPlayClick` which is also `buttonPlay`

```
fun buttonPlayClick(v: View)
{
    if (mp.isPlaying)
    {
        mp.pause()
        buttonPlay.text = "PLAY"

} else {
    mp.start()
        buttonPlay.text = "PAUSE"
    }
}
```

I am using the code below to point to a sound file

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a1)
```

Currently, the command is pointing to a sound file called a1 in res>raw

I am learning Kotlin bit by bit and I am trying to play a different sound file using the command below (changed a1 to x)

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x)
```

I was hoping that at some point in the app I can define `x = a1` or `a2` or `a3` to play different sounds files but it does not work like that. I also noticed that the sound files cannot just be an integer value. The sound files are very short (3 to 10 seconds)

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
var a1 = R.raw.a1
var a2 = R.raw.a2
var a3 = R.raw.a3
```

Or you can do it with `JAVA` like this :

```
int setMusic(String mMusic){
  return this.getResources().getIdentifier(mMusic, "raw", this.getPackageName());
}
```

and call it like this :

`mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, setMusic("a1"))`

or

`mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, setMusic("a2"))`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue but I cannot seem to get it working in a while loop. Is it possible to get it to work in a loop?

Comment: @Bob can you please explain more, you want to play a1, a2 a3 sequentially right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I figured it out by using this code to play different sounds depending on the value <if (firstSentence == 1) {
                                            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.a1)
                                        }
                                        if (firstSentence == 2) {
                                            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.a2)
                                        }>